# Encode Bitmap in Java ME

Tags: java, bitmap, blackberry, java-me, md5

I'm working on BB7 os and I need to implement Recognize.im functionality. 
I have problem with encode Bitmap to byte array and create byte array which contains cliect id and these bitmat. I was looking into Recognize documentation and there is method on Android which does it correctly:

```
public static String getMD5FromKeyAndImage(String clientKey, byte[] image) {
    String hash = null;
    try {
        java.security.MessageDigest md = java.security.MessageDigest
                .getInstance("MD5");
        md.reset();
        md.update(clientKey.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        md.update(image);
        byte[] array = md.digest();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
            sb.append(Integer.toHexString((array[i] & 0xFF) | 0x100)
                    .substring(1, 3));
        }
        hash = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        hash = null;
    }
    return hash;
}
```

and method which cast Bitmap to byte array:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
        options.inDither = true;
        options.inSampleSize = 4;
        image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, options);

        if (image == null) {
            return;
        }
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        pictureData = stream.toByteArray();
        image.recycle();
```

but those methods are not available on BB7. Is there any similar method which will give me the same result on Java ME?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [`Bitmap.createBitmapFromBytes`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Bitmap.html#createBitmapFromBytes(byte[],%20int,%20int,%20int))